# Sort items of Leaflet List Markers plugin control?

Tags: leaflet, markers, leaflet-plugins

I'm reading shapefiles with the leaflet library. I print the list of markers on the left in a list via the [Leaflet List Markers library](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-list-markers). I should sort the list of map markers that are shown to me on the screen  from the library. I tried to work on the leaflet-list-markers-js file but didn't find the way how to either sort the values into the array or how to sort the array once composed.

This piece of code I use to create the list, markersLayer is a LayerGroup:

```
var list = new L.Control.ListMarkers({layer: markersLayer, itemIcon: null, maxItems: 30, maxZoom: 25});

    list.on('item-mouseover', function (e) {
        e.layer.setIcon(redSelectMarker)
    }).on('item-mouseout', function (e) {
        e.layer.setIcon(transparentIcon)
    });


    myMap.addControl(list);
```

The following lines in the test to the methods that the library uses to update the page content list leaflet-list-markers.min.js, I have been working on this page. _updateList: adds the

html elements that are created with the _createItem method to the a._list list:

```
 _updateList: function () {
           var a = this, b = 0;
           this._list.innerHTML = "ELENCO PUNTI: ", this._layer.eachLayer(function (c) {
               c instanceof L.Marker && a._map.getBounds().contains(c.getLatLng()) && ++b < a.options.maxItems && a._list.appendChild(a._createItem(c))
           });
       },
```

```
_createItem: function (a) {
           var b = L.DomUtil.create("li", "list-markers-li"), c = L.DomUtil.create("a", "", b),
               d = this.options.itemIcon ? '<img src="' + this.options.itemIcon + '" />' : "", e = this;
           return c.href = "#", L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(c).on(c, "click", L.DomEvent.stop, this).on(c, "click", function (b) {
               this._moveTo(a.getLatLng())
           }, this).on(c, "mouseover", function (b) {
               e.fire("item-mouseover", {layer: a})
           }, this).on(c, "mouseout", function (b) {
               e.fire("item-mouseout", {layer: a})
           }, this), a.options.hasOwnProperty(this.options.label) ? c.innerHTML = d + '<span style="opacity: 1">' + a.options[this.options.label] + "</span> <b>" + this.options.itemArrow + "</b>" : console.log("propertyName '" + this.options.label + "' not found in marker"), b
       },
```

Comment: What is `L.Control.ListMarkers`? It's not part of vanilla Leaflet. Please edit your question and add info about this plugin.

Comment: This is the library I refer to: https://leafletjs.com/

Comment: Instead for the list of markers I use this library: https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-list-markers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.include` method to modify `._updateList` method of `L.Control.ListMarkers` control by adding sort of items before displaying them in control.

The modifying code could look like this (it has to be executed before control is used):

```
L.Control.ListMarkers.include({
  _updateList: function() {
    var that = this;
    var n = 0;
    var markers = [];

    this._list.innerHTML = '';
    this._layer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
      if(layer instanceof L.Marker)
        if( that._map.getBounds().contains(layer.getLatLng()) )
          if(++n < that.options.maxItems) {
            markers.push(layer);
          }
    });
    markers.sort(function(a, b) {
      var diff;
      if (a.options[that.options.label] > b.options[that.options.label])
        diff = 1;
      else if (a.options[that.options.label] < b.options[that.options.label])
        diff = -1;
      else {
        diff = 0;
      }
      return diff;
    });
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      that._list.appendChild(that._createItem(marker));
    });
  }
});
```

For the above code to work, `label` option has to be explicitly used when defining control, even if it has the default value `'title'`:

```
var list = new L.Control.ListMarkers({
  layer: markersLayer,
  label: 'title',
  itemIcon: null,
  maxItems: 30,
  maxZoom: 25
});
```